# Pull records for Audit Trail

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, audit-logging

I am implementing audit trail in my application. I followed [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506085627/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/041807-1.shtml) and [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/etechmentor/audit-trail-system/) created History table the tables that only needs to be audited.

I have a following tables to store the Patient information.

***TenantId*** represent each tenant data, since its a multitenant application

`Person` and `Patient` table

**Person**

Id, TenantId, FirstName, LastName, DOB, Mobile, Email,AddedBy,UpdatedBy, IsDeleted

**Patient**

Id, PatientIDentifier, IsOP, CanSendSMS, AddedBy, UpdatedBy, IsDeleted

Also another table

**Appointment**

Id, PatientId, AppointmentDate, DoctorId, Price, AddedBy, UpdatedBy

**AUDIT HISTORY TABLE STRUCTURE**

**PersonHistory**

AuditId,Id, FirstName, LastName, DOB, AddedBy, UpdatedBy, AuditUserId, AuditDate, Action

Here `Action` represents `A(ADD)/U(update)/D(delete)`

The same structure has been created for `Patient, Appointment`

Now I got triggers to insert into History table whenever add/delete/update happens.

Now I got the data available in the audit history table.

I have to write a query for two requirements.

1. Get all the records for a perticular patient. I need to pull all the records from PatientHostory, AppointmentHistory, PersonHistory by using a `PatientId`. How do we write SQL that takes more records from same table for given id? `UNION or JOIN`?
2. I need to take all the records from `all the HistoryTable for the supplied AuditUser Id`.

How can i write a query for this?

Comment: The `firstname`, `lastname` and `dob` in this table refer to the user or patient? Can you also or alternatively log the patient number?

Comment: @TI, `firstname, lastname` is not a part of a patient table. But when a patient is created, we add a record in person table for basic and then in patient table

Answer (score 2):

You would `UNION` the log data, also consider adding a `HistoryType` column to indicate which table it refers too

```
SELECT AuditId, Id, FirstName, LastName, DOB, AddedBy, UpdatedBy, 
       AuditUserId, AuditDate, Action, 'Person' HistoryType
FROM PersonHistory ph
JOIN Person p ON ph.id = p.id 
UNION ALL
SELECT AuditId,Id, FirstName, LastName, DOB, AddedBy, UpdatedBy, 
       AuditUserId, AuditDate, Action, 'Patient' HistoryType
FROM PatientHistory
UNION ALL    
SELECT AuditId,Id, FirstName, LastName, DOB, AddedBy, UpdatedBy, 
       AuditUserId, AuditDate, Action, 'Appointment' HistoryType
FROM AppointmentHistory
```

Turning the above into a `VIEW` would allow you to further query the data more easily

```
SELECT * FROM vAuditHistory
WHERE AuditUserId = 1234
```

If you need to get information from the 'originating' data i.e. `PatientId`s then again using the view you could do something along the lines of

```
DECLARE @PatientId VARCHAR(10) = '12345ABCDE'

SELECT h.*, p.PatientId
FROM vAuditHistory h
JOIN Patient pt ON pt.id = h.id
WHERE h.HistoryType = 'Patient'
AND pt.PatientId = @PatientId
UNION ALL
SELECT h.*, a.PatientId
FROM vAuditHistory h
JOIN Appointment a t ON a.id = h.id
WHERE h.HistoryType = 'Appointment'
AND pt.PatientId = @PatientId
```

or without the view

```
SELECT h.*, p.PatientId
FROM PatientHistory h
JOIN Patient pt ON pt.id = h.id
WHERE pt.PatientId = @PatientId
UNION ALL
SELECT h.*, a.PatientId
FROM AppointmentHistory h
JOIN Appointment a t ON a.id = h.id
WHERE pt.PatientId = @PatientId
```

Creating the above as an inline function would probably be useful